# Update core libraries ONLY from official repositories

Tags: apt, 18.04, official-repositories

Is there any way of installing core libraries ONLY from official repositories and don't accept those libraries offered in custom repositories if it has a different version than official?

Keep in mind that the custom repositories might offer some other packages as well, not offered by the official streams, but i do want to be able to install them but not the core libraries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could just comment out the custom repositories present in `/etc/apt/sources.list` using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, and not automatically: If you enable a source (in `/etc/apt/sources.list*`), you are telling apt that *you trust all of those packages completely*. Trust is binary (yes/no); there is not a spectrum of trust.

One easy solution is to use a snap-based version of the application instead a deb-based version.

Another easy solution to get newer software is to use a newer release of Ubuntu.